# Setting a tkinter window to be fullscreen using "-fullscreen" attribute after changing resolution with ctypes does not resize the window correctly

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a tkinter window that has been scaled using ctypes. When I try to make the window full-screen using the "-fullscreen" attribute, the window does not resize to cover the screen and instead, only covers half the screen.

Example:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import ctypes


window = tk.Tk()

window.tk.call('tk', 'scaling', 2)  ## Double the scale of the window
ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(2)  ## Double the resolution of the window

## Window now has double resolution with 1x scale

window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)  ## Making window full-screen doesn't work properly

window.mainloop()
```

Also, I don't know if this is related, but winfo_screenwidth/height returns an incorrect value for the screen width and height.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about replacing

```
window.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
```

with

```
window.geometry(f"{window.winfo_vrootwidth()}x{window.winfo_screenheight()}+{-7}+0")
```

did you?